# __modver_version_show undefined error when building linux kernel 3.0.4 version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compile, build, kernel-module

I tried to build the linux kernel 3.0.4 on ubuntu 11.10 in virtualbox. Here are my steps:

1. Download the source code
2. tar xjvf linux-source-3.0.0.tar.bz2
3. cd linux-source-3.0.0
4. make menuconfig, changed nothing but used the default config and save to .config
5. make

Actually I think it should be 3.0.4 because from the Makefile I could see

```
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 0
SUBLEVEL = 4
EXTRAVERSION =
```

Then at stage 2 which is to make modules, an error happened:

```
ERROR: "__modver_version_show" [drivers/staging/rts5139/rts5139.ko] undefined!
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Perhaps because 3.0.4 is a new release so that I can not find any same problem asked nor any solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

__modver_version_show() is an internal function which is only used when you have not enabled  CONFIG_MODULE **and** enabled CONFIG_SYSFS. IOW, **only** when you have CONFIG_SYSFS but not CONFIG_MODULE in your .config, you will see this error.

For normal desktops, !CONFIG_MODULE && CONFIG_SYSFS is a broken configuration.

Given the setups you did, you should copy the .config of your kernel provided by your distribution to the top directory of kernel source code first, and then do "make oldconfig".

I am not a ubuntu user, to find your distribution kernel .config, please either search your /boot or check if you have /proc/kconfig.gz, and copy it (you need zcat to copy kconfig.gz as it is compressed) to the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that the config of Ubuntu,

```
CONFIG_MODULE=Y
CONFIG_SYSFS=Y
```

I don't think the problem is due to this option. I tend to bypass this driver.

> Driver Module » Staging » RTS5139 »`<N>`